# How to set VertRefresh without restarting X?

Tags: xorg, xrandr, monitors, resolution

Suppose a second monitor is attached to a running system, and the video driver has some trouble getting this monitor's EDID to get its limits of operation. The monitor has a native resolution of 1280×1024, but the resolution is not in the list given by `xrandr` command. If we try to do `gtf`/`xrandr --newmode`/`xrandr --addmode` sequence, we'll get `BadMatch`, because X server thinks the monitor can't handle this mode.

This can be fixed by editing `xorg.conf` and setting explicit `HorizSync` and `VertRefresh` values there, but this means all running X applications must be stopped to restart Xorg. Note that [the suggestion](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=902402#p902402) to use `xrandr --fb` doesn't help here, and I don't see how it ever could.

OTOH, we have quite nice on-the-fly reconfiguration support by `xrandr` today, so I suppose there has to be a way to configure these options without restarting Xorg at all. Is it true? How can I do this?